# Porting data value to another worksheet based on a value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have researched formulas and lookups and index/match combos, but nothing. I am working with a large inventory database and recording weekly sales quantities items to track what is selling. Currently, I'm spending a lot of time adding the file to the workbook, toggling between the sheets, copying and pasting, using the find/select tool and entering the data. This takes forever. I have tried creating a search box, but still have to scroll down to find the highlighted result because it doesn't FIND the result the way the tool does.

What I need is to have the quantity brought to the database and entered next to the corresponding item. I am using the criteria from Column C on Sheet 1 to find the matching item in Column C on Sheet 2. I would like to be able to click a button and have a VBA import the sold quantity from Column D on Sheet 1 to the next empty column on Sheet 2. It sounds simple enough, but macros have failed me thus far. I have also tried a few VBA codes online, but having trouble changing the syntax to meet my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use use the [SUMSIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) function instead of a macro: 
=SUMIFS(*sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1*) 
=SUMIFS(*Weekly Sales Units, Weekly Sales ASIN, FBA Sold ASIN*) 
=SUMIFS('Weekly Sales'!D:D, 'Weekly Sales'!C:C, 'FBA Sold'!C3) 
Type the formula in cell S3 on sheet FBA Sold and copy down.

Comment: PERFECT! That worked beautifully! Thank you! That shaved HOURS off this task.